# Seeking Joomla module to display selected articles and their fields

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, custom-field, fields

Seeking for a module similar to DisplayNews with advanced functionality. I need to modify the display template in such way that it shows specific Joomla Fields of the articles selected.

Here is a link to custom fields documentation https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_custom_fields

So basically instead of such things as author, title, content I need to pull specific fields.

Comment: Articles Anywhere from Regular Labs can help you - also specific Custom Fields